# Edit JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, object

**I have the following javascript `object`:**

Note: I'm copying this from my browsers console

```
Object
content: "http://localhost/abito/website/secondary_imgs.php?imgId=18&imgTitle=Hugo%20Boss%20Sweat-Top%20-%20Skaz%20in%20Grey&mWidth=593&mHeight=900"
gallery: "New Arrivals"
link: HTMLAnchorElement
options: Object
player: "iframe"
title: "Hugo Boss Sweat-Top - Skaz in Grey(front)"
__proto__: Object
```

It is being created by the plugin Shadowbox.js, so I have no control over it's creation.

My question is, is there any way I can edit the `content` part of the `Object`, and then place it back in the `Object`?

The `Object` is already referenced to the variable `c`. I am able to reference the `content` with the following: `var url = c.content`. What I am unsure of is how to edit the `content`, and then place it back inside the `object` for use.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just assign to it: `c.content = (edited content here)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `c` refers to the object, then you simply need to assign a different value to the properties you want to change, like this.

```
c.content = 'what you want';
c.gallery = 'new gallery';
```

etc. But I'm not sure what you will be able to achieve with this anyway, it all depends on how and when those values are being read.

Comment: I am placing the object `c` into the function `Shadowbox.open(c)` which works properly. I think that's what you are referring to. I will test this out. Thank you.

Comment: Then it's most surely used as a settings object to alter the behavior of the open method, it should work if you modify its content before calling the open method.